# "Estar" vs "ser" usage with "muy bien"

Tags: gramática, verbos, cópulas

> Está muy bien

Why not say "Es muy bien"?

In what context would you use "está muy bien"? What noun could you refer "estar" to? Could you refer "estar" to a person, place or thing?

Could you say the following?

> Él está muy bien
>
> Su salud está muy bien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use *estar bien/mal* with people, things, places and situations that are good/bad and can change that state during time. You use *es bueno/malo* for (usually) permanent qualities, as being a good person or a nice place to stay.

*Está muy bien* is most of the time "S/he/it very well". Examples:

```
¿Cómo está el coche? (preguntándole a tu mecánico)
Está muy bien. Le he cambiado el aceite y limpiado los filtros pero no tenía nada raro.

¿Cómo está Luisa? Me dijo su madre que estaba muy estresada en el trabajo.
Eso fue al principio, ahora está muy bien.

¿Cómo está la situación en el Consejo?
No muy bien, no alcanzan acuerdos y el tiempo se agota.
```

*Su salud está muy bien* is correct, and you could say (and I'm more used to):

```
(él/ella) está  muy bien (de salud, económicamente, etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

"Es muy bien" is incorrect in every context. @Lucas examples are good, they all use the verb "estar" (never "ser").